# React formatting for render -- syntax -- unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, syntax, frontend

I was wondering why my formatting is wrong for my React class? It says theres supposed to be a paranthesis but I do include a paranthesis? I might be forgetting some aspect of the syntax format, though :( 
This is my a snippet from my js file:

```
function App() {
  state = {
    posts = []; 
    input = '';
  };
  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.getPosts();
  };
  getPosts = () => {
    axios.get('(server)')
    // replace (server) with server link
      .then((response) => {
        const data = response.data;
        this.setState({ posts: data });
      })
  }
  displayBlogPost = (posts) => {
    if (!posts.length) return null;
    return posts.map((post, index) => (
      <div key={index} className="post__display">
        <h3>"name " + post.name </h3>
        <h3>"City " + post.location </h3>
        <h3>"Requesting " + post.type </h3>
        <h3> post.message </h3> 
      </div>
    ));
  };

  render() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
        <header> 
            <h2> Covunity </h2> 
            <SearchExample items= { this.state.posts } />
        </header>
            </div>
        <div className="gallery"> 
        {this.displayBlogPost(this.state.posts)} </div> 
    )
    document.getElementById('root')
  }
}
```

and the error message is

```
Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected ";" (54:12)
```

(at render())

Answer (score 0):

First, you must return a single element. Instead you return 2. Then, the last line in the render method implementation is unreachable (after the return). Try this:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="App">
        <header>
          <h2> Covunity </h2>
          <SearchExample items={this.state.posts}/>
        </header>
      </div>
      <div className="gallery">
        {this.displayBlogPost(this.state.posts)}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
  // document.getElementById('root')
}
```

Comment: Okay, just tried that, but Im still getting an error on that line  - same error

Comment: als, dont we need getElementById

Comment: @ManaalSiddiqui, you need it in [`ReactDOM.render()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#render) **not** inside your component's `render()` method.